# Hosted Service RabbitMQ connection failure using Docker Compose

Tags: masstransit

Here is the log

```
MassTransit.RabbitMqTransport.Integration.ConnectionContextFactory.CreateConnection(ISupervisor supervisor)
[02:51:48 DBG] Connect: guest@localhost:5672/
[02:51:48 WRN] Connection Failed: rabbitmq://localhost/
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable
```

The RabbitMQ control panel is showing the exchanges and queues as created and when I make a publish request I see the queue come through but then get a MassTransit timeout as it tries to respond.

Here is my docker yaml setup. I assume MassTransit pulls its settings to connect from appsettings.json.

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  
  hostedservice:
   environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=development
   ports:
      - "80"
      
  rabbitmq3:
        hostname: "rabbitmq"
        image: rabbitmq:3-management
        environment:
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=guest
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=guest
            - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST=/  
        ports:
            # AMQP protocol port
             - '5672:5672'
            # HTTP management UI
             - '15672:15672'
```

Comment: You are trying to connect from one container to another. In this case, you should use the container hostname (`rabbitmq`), not `localhost`.

Comment: Hi Alexey I changed it to rabbitmq in both my yaml and appsettings.json but localhost is still appearing in the debug output. [02:51:48 DBG] Connect: guest@localhost:5672/
[02:51:48 WRN] Connection Failed: rabbitmq://localhost/

Comment: If you don't configure RMQ transport, it will default to using localhost. Here's an example of a proper config http://masstransit-project.com/usage/transports/rabbitmq.html#broker-topology

Comment: OK thanks I am using the SagaStateMachine setup as in the MassTransit Twitch Sample.Service. https://github.com/MassTransit/Sample-Twitch/blob/master/src/Sample.Service/Program.cs Adding RabbitMq, MongoDB for event and statemachine repository. It runs fine non container but when I setup docker yml its giving me that connection failure. I have just added docker compose yaml as above. I assume MassTrasnit has its connection with RabbitMQ and then RabbitMQ is setup to communicate as a container?

Comment: sorry still no success. learning a lot but can't get past this hurdle.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using the MassTransit Docker template to get a working setup. Or you can look [at the source code](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit-Templates/blob/master/src/Content/MassTransit.Docker/Program.cs#L47) and see how when running in a container, the template using `rabbitmq` as the host name to connect.

You can [download the template](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MassTransit.Templates/) using NuGet.

Comment: Thanks Chris this allows me to create a cleaner sagastatemachine hosted service.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Chris that moved me to the container template usage that cleared up the connection issue!